# How to export vector images from TeXworks

Tags: graphics, pseudocode

I use TeXworks to write pseudo-codes. How can I export the codes into a vector image such as in .emf? The image should have a size fit for the codes. For example, if the codes only takes half page, the image should be half-page large instead of a whole page with half page blank space.

Comment: find a essentially the same question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18836/export-algorithm-as-pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [standalone](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) documentclass to create a pdf exactly the size of your pseudocode example. Then you can either include the pdf directly into another tex document via `\includegraphics{}`. Or you can open the pdf in a vector graphics software, like Adobe Illustrator, Corel Draw or [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/). Inkscape can open pdf and export to emf.

A MWE for a pseudocode standalone document could look like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
% ==== ==== ==== ====
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
If a=true then
  x=5;
elseif b=true then
  x=7;
end if;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```